# Why Is "this" Undefined in Vue 3 Function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Take a look at the following simple component example in Vue 3:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Test',
  setup(){
    return{
      one,
      two
    }
  }
})

function one(){
  console.log(this) //<-- Proxy{}
  two()
}

function two(){
  console.log(this) //<-- undefined
}
</script>
  
<template>
  <a href="#" @click.prevent="one()">Start</a>
</template>
```

I'm trying to understand why `this` is `undefined` in the `two()` function when it's called from the `one()` function. Both functions are returned in `setup()`, so I would expect them to both have access to `this`.

This being said, how do I then get a reference to the component instance of `this` inside my `two()` function?

Comment: Just don't rely on `this` with composition API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine Vue still has to obey the rules of Javascript. When an Event handler is invoked, typically it's in the context of the object receiving the event. In this case, `one()` is invoked with `this` bound to the `Proxy` for the `<a>` element.

However, `two()` is invoked specifically *without a context* (ie: `two()` instead of `someobject.foo()`). Which means `this` will be undefined.

I'm not terribly familiar with Vue, but I imagine it doesn't do automatic method binding so as not to require you to pay for things you don't use.

Since `this` is bound correctly in `one()`, you can actually call `two()` as a method of `this` instead of as a bare function:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Test',
  setup(){
    return{
      one,
      two
    }
  }
})

function one(){
  console.log(this) //<-- Proxy{}
  this.two()
}

function two(){
  console.log(this) //<-- Proxy{}
}
</script>
  
<template>
  <a href="#" @click.prevent="one()">Start</a>
</template>
```

Comment: *I imagine it doesn't do automatic method binding so as not to require you to pay for things you don't use* - it does but only for functions specified in `methods`, which is legacy API.